# Expected handling of synchronisation with multiple controls in React/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

My situation is the following: I have four "combobox" selectors. The content of each selector depends on the picked option in the previous ones.

Each select emits a specific action, say the first emits ACTION_COMBO_1, the second ACTION_COMBO_2 etc.. The reducer receives the actions (say, ACTION_COMBO_1), and now needs to synchronize the contents of the following three other selectors. As I understand, emitting more actions from within an action is an antipattern, but the resulting consequence is as ugly: for each action handler in the reducer, I must in any case go through the rest of the state and update it within that part of the handler, meaning that

- in the reducer for selector 1, I must also write code to update selector 2 state, followed by selector 3 state, followed by selector 4 state.
- in the reducer for selector 2, I must write code to update selector 3 and selector 4 state.
- in the reducer for selector 3, I must write code to update selector 4.

Which is to be expected. Is there a mitigation strategy or different, more canonical approach I am not aware of to actually handle cases like this one?

Comment: Can you show a simplified representation of your state and reducer? Is there a reason that you need an action for each of your combo, it seems weird not to have only one.

Comment: @Axnyff I need an action for each combo because they need to update their own state (i.e. which entry is selected)

Comment: cant you just setup all your state at a single location. `{ combo: { state1, state2, state3, state4 }}` and update the field that you need when dispatching?

Comment: @StefanoBorini: what about this action : { type: 'ACTION_COMBO', id: 2}

Comment: "emitting more actions from within an action is an antipattern" Not if you use thunk for example, that's not an antipattern and quite common.